# Compiz crashed after a few tweaks, and now I cannot start it again!

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

Recently, I was meddling with ccsm and the window kept refreshing with every plugin addition (which is normal i suppose). However, after i enabled SVG (I dont think this is relevant but i included it anyway) under image loading, suddenly it got hung! Unity crashed, as i couldn't see a top bar or a launcher! My window decorations were out too! I restarted the computer hoping it would fix anything, but it didn't work!

Right now, all i can see on the screen in my mouse, the wallpaper and my desktop icons. Right click works for me, and i can drag icons around the desktop. I can even run chrome (using docky which works too (except its in 2D, not in 3D))

I tried using unity --reset and unity --replace from the recovery console, but every time it hung.

```
Initializing core options...done
```

When I tried running compiz --replace, it came back with this

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display
compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core
```

When I try running metacity --replace:

```
Window manager error: unable to open X display
```

When I try to run ccsm from the recovery, It doesn't start up

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from ccm.Conflicts import *
File"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 26, in <module>
  from ccm.Constants import *
File"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Constants.py", line 30, in <module>
  CurrentScreenNum = gtk.gdk.display_get_default().get_default_screen().get_number()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'
```

Please help me, and ask if you need any more info. XD

Thanks a ton!
Ciao

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to solve. Pretty funny though!

It was quite simple actually, rather than trying to launch ccsm from the recovery console, i started nautilus (From Docky, which was working for me), and went to "Computer/usr/bin" (On Ubuntu 12.10). From there I could launch ccsm and found out that all plugins were disabled. I went ahead and added in unity and other plugins, and everything's back to normal!

Hope this helps everyone who has a similar problem!

Ciao!
Pranay